# Empty Errors in Eclipse Problems View

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I recently converted my work dev environ from Idea to Eclipse. I've got everything in and building properly, but I have 23 empty error messages in my Problems view. I can still build everything despite these errors, but it is quite annoying to have the "Errors in project" popup when building.

The project "Web_ImageViewer" is a GWT project.

I have a hunch that these errors are somehow related to ignoring GWT output folders, but I'm not sure.

I can delete these errors, but they just come back. Anyone have any idea how I can permanently get rid of these? Or if they are actually trying to tell me something useful?

(I can't post an Image since I'm a new user)

Comment: Sometimes, closing and reopening the project helps if something very strange like this happens. Did you also try "Project > Clean..."?

Comment: I opened the following bug -> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417538

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check the Problems tab "Type" column to see what validator the errors are being generated from.  If the errors are useless, try turning off that kind of validation and doing a clean and build.  Go to Preferences > Validation at the global level, or turn off validation for individual projects by right-clicking project > Properties > Validation

I regularly turn off my HTML validator since the HTML isn't well-formed when you are working with JSPs.

**Update**

Seems like a lot of people are narrowing unknown errors down to the **Web (2.2-2.4) Validator**.  Try turning that one off and rebuilding.

Comment: The Problem "Type" is listed only as "Validation Message". Path is empty, Location is "Unknown". I suppose I could play with the validation types until the problem disappears..

Comment: No other details if you right-click or double-click or something?  That's very strange.

Comment: I agree. No other details with double-click. Right-click->Properties shows: empty Description, Creation time, Severity=Error, On Element=Web_ImageViewer, empty InFolder, empty Location.

Comment: I ended up just turning off my validators, as suggested. I don't think this is the best course of action, but is at least pointing in the right direction.

Comment: This happend to me and I narrowed it down to the "Web (2.2-2.4) Validator".  YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 13):

I narrowed it down to "Web (2.2-2.4) Validator". After disabling it you need to Clean the project for the error to disappear.

Answer (score 12):

I was also facing the same error, it worked with simple trick. I selected my web project and `right click>validate` .Voila , error disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me where clean or closing and reopening didn't

Comment: Can say this was also the solution for my case.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by closing the project and deleting **WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/PROJECT/.markers**

WORKSPACE is your current workspace folder and PROJECT is the name of your project.

Comment: I wiped my workspace folder and it also solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well.

I can get the error by first adding the `.jar` to the `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder`, and then adding it to the classpath/Build Path.

I can avoid this error by placing the `.jar` in a different folder; for example, I created a `/lib` folder.

My guess is that the error occurs because the folder it is in (`/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`) is also the folder that it is typically exported to.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms: Validation Messages with no description, location "unknown", created by the  `Web (2.2-2.4) Validator`.

The reason in my case was that the web project depended on two library (utility) projects and both of these contained the same jar file in their respective lib folders.
I deleted the jar in one of them, removed the references to the deleted jar and voila, the errors disappeared.

Comment: you only hide the problem not solving it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this kind of empty errors because of wrong workspace setting for text encoding.
When I fixed this (Menu > Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding), everything goes well.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This error has gone for my case by disabling setting validation of maven in window preference java EE maven validation .

Answer (score 0):

You should do 2 things:

1- Project > Clean

2- Try to hide unwanted folders (output folder with stuff you don't want validated)

http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2005/7/7/Hiding-FilesFolders-From-Eclipse-Projects-Using-Filters

Eclipse has strange behaviours sometimes. You can also try to remove your project from eclipse, clean it by hand and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: 78 empty validation errors from unknown source and blank text.
The problem was that somehow I ended up using the `webapp` source folder as a running Tomcat context folder, and my source WEB-INF was filled with `lib` and `tld` folders. 
Once I deleted those folders (especially the tld one) the problems disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,but I only got one.

```
Location:unknown Type:Validation Message
```

I solved it by formatting the "`/WEB-INF/web.xml`".That means I removed all the unuseful "`blank space`","`\r\n`","`\t`".

Good luck and I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a Maven GWT project in Eclipse. I found out that when I do Maven->Update Project, that results in jars being put in to the WEB-INF/lib directory that are also in the Maven dependencies (Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Maven Dependencies). So every time I do Maven->Update Project (which I do if I introduce new dependencies), I have to delete the jars it creates from WEB-INF/lib, and then launch the project (or do a GWT Compile) to make the errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed this by (Menu > Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding), change the Text file encoding to "UTF-8"(default is MS950) for my web project, then it works!

Answer (score -1):

Here is one more thing you can try which worked for me while anything else failed.

Right click on your project -> Team -> Refresh/Cleanup

As we are using SVN this did a SVN cleanup and triggered a project rebuild. After this my problems were back again :)